# How to pass parameters to child CMD

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

My question relates to the previous question,
[How to run a batch script in a separate instance of cmd.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581893/how-to-run-a-batch-script-in-a-separate-instance-of-cmd-exe). But it doesn't work, so I want to explain my problem exactly.

1. My platform is Windows 7, but it's same in Windows XP to 10, I think.
2. I set an environment variable via setx.exe in a .cmd script. (works)
3. I want to execute "my.jar" with `java -jar my.jar`, which needs the environment variable. Running it from the current CMD won't work because the variable isn't defined. So I tried the following ways around this:

   1. Open a new CMD from the first with `start "" /i Java -jar my.jar`. I tried roughly all `start` options! (fail, no scope)
   2. Open a new CMD from the first with `start %windir%/Explorer "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe"` and type in `java -jar my.jar`. (works, scope ok)

I want to implement the working solution (3.2) in a batch file, but it fails:

```
setx var "blabla"
start %windir%/Explorer "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe"
???
```

How can I pass the parameters `java.exe -jar my.jar` to the second CMD?

Comment: What is `start %windir%/Explorer "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe"` supposed to do? Have you tried `start "" [/I] cmd /K java -jar "my.jar"`, so the `java` command line appears in a new `cmd` instance (replace `/K` by `/C` for the `cmd` window to be closed automatically)? Anyway, state `setx var "blabla"` **and** `set "var=blabla"`, so `var` becomes set in new and in the current `cmd` instances...

Comment: Can the java.exe be found in the PATH? Windows has something like registered executables (that will be used when the PATH variable is at least defined - crazy enough). I don't know, whether these registered executables inherit the environment of the caller - when multiple explorer instances are running ...

Comment: Path settings are ok.
start %windir%/Explorer "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" do nothing but starting a new cmd with a WM_SETTINGCHANGE call.
This is what i want, but also do my jar...calls, but i think its not working.
Manually yes, but not in a script

Answer (score 1):

setx does global changes to the windows installation which will be present most likely after reboot (or when you start processes from the right explorer instance).

```
set var="blabla"
```

is probably what you want.

Comment: Or combine `set` with setx.exe if you need both.

Comment: setx.exe defaults to modifying the user's persistent environment variables in `HKCU\Environment`, which is stored in the user's profile directory, so the default isn't modifying the Windows installation. It broadcasts a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message to notify top-level windows that the environment has changed on disk. Explorer immediately reloads its environment when it receives this message, so running CMD from Explorer inherits the updated environment.

Comment: thnaks eryksun, thats exaktly the behaviour i found out and so i start the app with CMD from Explorer. But i failed in passing arguments. SET doesn't work. I can see the Var with "SET" but the app didnt recognize it. Also not in childs. Only SETX was working.

Comment: @Dan, if you are launching the application from the batch file, `SET` should work.  In rare cases you might need both `SET` and `SETX` but you really really shouldn't ever need to mess around trying to launch the child via Explorer.

Comment: @Dan: do you have activated the windows option to use a separate explorer instance for the desktop and the folder windows? This leads to two explorer.exe instances in your session that have different 'behaviour' regarding environment variables.

Comment: I did a lot of research and these are my results:
1) Set is not working at all
2) SETX works, but only after a restart or with start %windir%/Explorer "%windir%\system32\cmd.exe" (or by clicking start/ run cmd.exe) because WM_SETTINGSCHANGE is send. see eryksun's answer.
 And like my origin question, i am not able to pass a parameter to this call (in a script).
So best solution seems to tell the user to do a restart (what i want avoid).

Comment: I still do not know why %windir%/Explorer is required in the start command and why the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message is required. If you write a command file with `set key=val` and `start cmd` you open a command window where key is set. Have you tried to use `java -Dkey=val`?